# unwanted para tag `<p>` is coming at the end of the section in tex4ht

Tags: sectioning, tex4ht, para

I am trying to change the `\Configure{section}` for the customized tag `<div>` and `<title>`

I am using the below tex coding

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{macros}

\newenvironment{exe}{Exercise: }{}

    \begin{document}
    \section{sample}
    This version uses the powerful Uniscribe library in order to better handle Unicode and complex language processing (including support for bidirectional text).

    This version uses the powerful Uniscribe library in order to better handle Unicode and complex language processing (including support for bidirectional text).
    \end{document}
```

In the cfg file i have modified like below

```
\Configure{section}
    {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
    \HCode{<section class="section\thesection"\a:LRdir>}\TitleMark}
    {\EndP\HCode{</section>}}
    {\HCode{<title>}}
    {\HCode{</title>}\HtmlParOn\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}
```

when the tex file having only one section I am getting the correct output like below

```
<section class="section0.1"><label>0.1</label><title><a id="x1-10000.1"></a>sample</title>
<p class="noindent">This version uses the powerful Uniscribe library in order to better handle Unicode and complex language processing (including support for bidirectional text).</p>
<p class="indent">This version uses the powerful Uniscribe library in order to better handle Unicode and complex language processing (including support for bidirectional text).</p>
</section>
```

when we add another section in the .tex file the extra `<p>` is coming before the section like below

```
<section class="section0.1"><label>0.1</label><title><a id="x1-10000.1"></a>sample</title>
<p class="noindent" >This version uses.</p>
<p class="indent" >   This version uses the text).</p>
<p class="noindent" ></p>
<p class="indent" > 
</section>
</p>
<section class="section0.2"><label>0.2</label><title><a id="x1-20000.2"></a>sample</title>
<p class="noindent" >This version uses.</p>
<p class="indent" >   This version uses the text).</p>
</section>
```

How to suppress the extra `<p> ... </p>` tag in the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of wrong paragraph instances can be fixed using `\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP` before the problematic tag:

```
\Configure{section}
{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
\HCode{<section class="section\thesection"\a:LRdir>}\TitleMark}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</section>}}
{\HCode{<title>}}
{\HCode{</title>}\HtmlParOn\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}
```

It produces the following result:

```html
 <section class="section0.1"><span class="titlemark">0.1   </span><title><a 
 id="x1-10000.1"></a>sample</title>
<p class="noindent">This version uses the powerful Uniscribe library in order to better handle
Unicode and complex language processing (including support for bidirectional
text).
</p><p class="indent">   This version uses the powerful Uniscribe library in order to better handle
Unicode and complex language processing (including support for bidirectional
text).
</p>
   </section> 
<section class="section0.2"><span class="titlemark">0.2   </span><title><a 
 id="x1-20000.2"></a>another section</title>
<p class="noindent">some text </p></section>
```

Comment: I have tried with your answer, but i am getting  dummy para tag before the second Head`<p class="noindent" ></p>`,  due to the blank line is present bfore the \section in the tex file, if i closed with the previous para the empty `<p>'  tag is removed in the html file. How to handle with this situation?

Comment: @VenkatesanRamachandiran could you update your question with some concrete example?